# Scala Dispatcher - Bind a set of Actors to a predefined set of threads

Tags: scala, akka

I am using Akka. I am trying to work out how to bind a set of actors (in the thousands) so that each unique actor is handled by the same thread.
For example, my OS has 24 native threads, I have 1000 actors each handling a unique piece of data: d1, d2, d3, .. dn and I always want d1 to be handled by the same thread 1.
In Java I would pre-allocate 24 threads and maintain a map of ids to threads, allocating them in a round robin fashion.
Example: 2 threads, 5 data 
d1,d3, d5 th1
d2, d4 th2

I have looked at the Akka documentation and out of the 4 dispatchers, none meet my needs. The closest one is PinnedDispatcher - but it keeps creating native threads and the result is an OOME.

Any idea about this apart from the creation of my own Dispatcher?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create your own dispatcher, you only need to create your own ExecutorService that you provide to any dispatcher using a ExecutorServiceConfigurator so that when the actor is scheduled to be executed you send it to "its" Thread. You could essentially keep a map of single-threaded [ExecutorServices](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29)

Hope that helps!

Cheers,
√

Comment: Thank you Victor. Indeed I could create a class that extends ExecutorServiceConfigurator and provide its FQN to the application.conf. However, in the extended class of ThreadPoolExecutor and the overridden method execute, I would need to work out the actor id - any hint on this please?

Comment: What is passed to execute is the Mailbox, which will be the same on every submission.So either you use a ConcurrentIdentityHashMap[Mailbox, ExecutorService] or you get the hashCode and map that (using modulo or whatnot) to an ExecutorService.

Comment: And you don't want to extend ThreadPoolExecutor. You just want a conceptual ExecutorService that delegates to internal newSingleThreadExecutor's. Also, remember that Futures etc will also be executed, so it's probably a better idea to go with hashCode + module than to keep a map, and then for non-Mailboxes that are executed, use ThreadLocalRandom + module to pick somewhere to execute them.

Comment: Thx. Yep - I coded it that way. Thx v much - Would be nice to have a default implementation for this.

Comment: Victor, do you think this could be added to Akka?

Comment: I wouldn't rule that out. The general benefit of it must be proven first.

Comment: I have lots of example to give you from the financial industry (pricing, quoting, ...)

Comment: How can I prove the benefit to you?

Comment: By providing an implementation and list pros/cons/performance

Comment: So, you are asking for an enhancement of akka with the pros to be posted here?

Comment: Sort of, I think the akka-user mailing list is a better venue for such endeavours.

Comment: Viktor, I might have missed something here. Going back to this and the actual type of the Runnable passed to the ExecutorService, I see akka.dispatch.Dispatcher$$anon$1@33d9a5bb and TaskInvocation(akka.event.EventStream@6ea920ad,akka.dispatch.Future$$anon$4@21a0769d,<function0>) so I am a bit confused about what type should I test on?

Comment: It should use the same one each time, so just keep an ConcurrentIdentityHashMap or similar